# mapping ajax data to jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having the json data as

data.json file

```
 {

  "response":[
        {"id":1,"name":"Crime","rel":4},
        {"id":2,"name":"Murder","rel":5},
        {"id":3,"name":"Horror","rel":6},
        {"id":4,"name":"Comedy","rel":1},
       {"id":5,"name":"Novel","rel":2,}
     ]
  }
```

and the ajax call is..

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
      $.ajax({
           url: "data.json",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
           "use strict";
            main(response);
          }
  });
 }
}
```

and as I want the rel attribute of each item am trying with jquery mapping

```
    $.fn.tagcloud = function(options) {

       var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.tagcloud.defaults, options);
      var tagWeights = this.map(function(){
      return $(this).attr("rel");
    });
```

how can i get response into the above function and
 where am getting tagWeights empty so how can I retreive tag weights
 and am trying make it into array

```
 tagWeights = jQuery.makeArray(tagWeights).sort(compareWeights);
```

So how can I get the attribute "rel" data

Answer (score 1):

Problem here you are using JSON not XML or DOM. So avoid using attr() of jquery function.

You can try like this inside main function.

```
var tagWeights = response.map(function(item){
     return item.rel;
 });

tagWeights.sort(compareWeights);
```

Comment: @roy Can you setup fiddle for this problem.?